# Locating Functions within Excel Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using an Excel Macro to create a 4D graph with the ThreeDify Add-In. When I record the Macro, it doesn't pick up any command I perform using the Add-in. I can go in and edit the code, but I can't find commands that will insert my data into the graph/ThreeDify. Is there a way to locate or view the Add-In formulas from Excel?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to see all the functions that are available to you in the Object Browser in the VB Editor.

In the VB Editor, strike the **F2** key, then select the AddIn VBA Project in the drop-down at tyhe top, then the classes/modules will be listed in the listbox on the left, and when you click on each one you can see the (public) functions or procedures.

here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: But if the authors of the ThreeDify Add-In did not provide an API, then unfortunately you will be unable to adjust it programmatically.