# Locating Lost Excel Macro Formula From Old Data Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm resurrecting some old scientific data from the early 2000s.

I need to locate the custom functions that allowed the data to be shown. The spreadsheet that I have is full of `#REF!` cells, as they are supposed to be calculated based on a custom-defined formula (here, called 'RESECTION').

How do I find this formula? If I can see the math it was performing, I will be able to use this old data, and extend our timeseries significantly.

The spreadsheet is an ".xlsm" document. There is an associated file that is ".XLM"; it provides some GUI-like functionality that is now broken, and I do not see how to access the commands (?) or other VBA that is inside.

I have not had success with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566602/locating-functions-within-excel-macros).

File with the VBA [can be found here; SURVEY.XLM.](https://github.com/ehbaker/StackOverflow)

Problem is seen here; calling function from SURVEY.XLM. How do I access the formula within here?

I can see that the formula is in there; how do I see the calculation it performs?
[image]

Comment: Where do you see a function?  I only see range references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RESECTION` is a named range refering to cell A4 on the hidden `Survey` sheet.

In the VBE immediate window type `thisworkbook.Sheets(2).visible = true` and then `thisworkbook.Sheets(2).select`.

Cell `Survey!A4` contains the value `=RESULT(64)`.

The rest of the sheet contains the macros - first time I've seen or tried to use a filled in macro sheet.
I tried `Ctrl+F`to find the definition of `RESULT` but it comes up with `Macro error at cell [SURVEY.XLM]SURVEY!A364`.